# How to select all a elements from a p class?

Tags: css

How can I select all **a** elements inside a **p** element that have a specific class name?

```
<div>
  <p class="myClass">
    This is
    <div>
      <a href="#">random</a>
    </div>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with the code? Please explain the code a little bit.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code, I need to select all `a` elements using a parent class name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the div inside the **p** tag:

```
<div>
  <p class="myClass">
      <a href="#">random</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Then if you want to select all the **a** tags inside a **p** tag which you gave a class. You can do the following:

```
.myClass a {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

May be you aren't able to target anchor tag(s) due to that div. Do you need that div before the anchor tag? Please refer to the code snippet below:

```css
.myClass a {
    color: green;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="myClass">
    This is
      <a href="#">random</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`div *[href]
{
       // css rules...
}`

```
<div>  
     <p class="myClass"> This is 
       <div>
            <a href="#">random</a> 
       </div> 
     </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<p>` can only contain inline elements,See [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1).

so,remove `div` inside `p`:

```css
p.myClass a {
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="myClass">
    This is<br>
    <a href="#">random</a>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give a specific class name to **a** and call it like:

```
<a class="myA's" href="#">random</a>
```

CSS

```
a.myA's{
#do something
}
```

And in your case it should be:

```
.myClass > a{
#doSmthg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `<p>` to `<div>` then use this

```
.myClass > div a  { ... }`
```

or remove `<div>` inside the `<p>` and try this

```
p.myClass a { ... }
```